# Problems animating UIView alpha

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm trying to apply a fade to an UIView I created programmatically on the top of another.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void) {
    [self.view setAlpha:0];
}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                 }];
```

The finished event is called properly after exactly 0.5 seconds, but I don't see any fade (I should see the UIView on the bottom).

If instead of using the alpha, I move away the UIView it works (I see the bottom UIView while the top UIView slides away), so it seems to be a problem related to alpha, but I can't figure out what's wrong!

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void) {
    CGRect o = self.view.frame;
    o.origin.x = 320;
    self.view.frame = o;
}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                 }];
```

I used alpha animations previously and they works in this way usually...

Comment: Why you set alp[ha to 0

Comment: Is the view flagged as opaque? Alpha transitions won't work then.

Comment: your code working fine.

Answer (score 7):

Try setting `opaque` to `NO` explicitly. I had the same problem and setting that solved my problem. Apparently, opaque views just don't seem to play well with alpha.

Credit goes to Hampus Nilsson's comment though.

Answer (score 2):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut 
animations:^{
    [self.view setAlpha:0];
} 
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}];
```

This will work right, and your fading will be nicer, because of `options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut`.

Answer (score 2):

I experience same issue in my case its because of thread 
So i end up with write animation block in main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{        
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews animations:^{
        View.alpha = 0.0f;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
});
```

Comment: Plus 1 because I had a case where animating alpha had no effect, and adding the dispatch_async() block fixed it.  Later, I realized that another method was messing around with alpha values, and of course, doing exactly as programmed, but it took me a couple of days to find my error.  Meanwhile, your suggestion got me going on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact problem. In my case, I wanted the view to be hidden at first, so I set `hidden` to `true`. I thought changing the `alpha` value changes `hidden` property automatically, but that wasn't the case.

So, if you want the view to be hidden at first, set its `alpha` to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

One more piece of the puzzle.  When you're animating constraints, you can set the new constraint constants outside of an animation block and then call `layoutIfNeeded` inside the animation.

With view alphas, these need to be set directly inside the animation block.

Change this:

```
//setup position changes
myConstraint.constant = 10
myOtherConstraint.constant = 10
//whoops, alpha animates immediately
view.alpha = 0.5

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
   //views positions are animating, but alpha is not   
   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

to

```
//setup position changes
myConstraint.constant = 10
myOtherConstraint.constant = 10

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
   view.alpha = 0.5
   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, and none of the suggestions worked for me. I overcame the problem by using the layer opacity instead.
This is the code for showing the layer (using Xamarin, but you'll get the idea):

```
        //Enter the view fading
        zoomView.Layer.Opacity = 0;

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View.Add(zoomView);

        UIView.AnimateNotify(
            0.15, // duration
            () => { zoomView.Layer.Opacity = 1.0f },
            (finished) => { }
        );
```

And this is for fading out the same zoomView

```
UIView.AnimateNotify(
                0.15, // duration
                () => { zoomView.Layer.Opacity = 0; },
                (finished) =>
                {
                    if (finished)
                    {
                        zoomView.RemoveFromSuperview();
                    }
                }
            );
```