# UIView doesn't animate alpha

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I am trying to animate `alpha` of my view but I couldn't get it to working.

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
    self.alpha = 0;
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    self.alpha = 1;
}];
```

The animation works, but alpha is static at 1. The transform animates correctly though. If I remove setting the transform (just to test if it's caused by that), nothing happens.

I've also tried repeating the animation, it repeats but alpha is always 1:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:delay
  options:(UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
         | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
         | UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone) animations:^{
    self.alpha = 0;
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if(finished){
        self.alpha = 1;
    }
  }];
```

Why could this be?

Comment: @picciano it is not answered. a comment under the question solved my problem, not it's answer.

Comment: The problem and solution are the same, which is why I marked it as duplicate. Go ahead and answer the other question and grab the credit.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. It had multiple issues. First one, the view was `opaque`. I've set opaque to `NO` and nothing happened. Then I've realized that I was starting with `alpha = 0`, I've also changed that and it started animating the way I wanted.

Credit goes to Hampus Nilsson's comment here: [Problems animating UIView alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916162/problems-animating-uiview-alpha-ios?rq=1#comment27926408_18916162)