# Perform UIView background color animation simultaneously with UITableView beginUpdates/endUpdates animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation

I have a table view cell and when tapped it will:

- animate it's height (so I need a `beginUpdates/endUpdates` call)
- animate the alpha of a subview

When I have `beginUpdates/endUpdates` call, the cell animates it's height perfectly, but the alpha of the subview keeps "jumping" to the target value without animating. When I remove `beginUpdates/endUpdates` and try to animate the alpha regularly, it animates well, but this time I don't have the cell expanding height animation.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)handleTap{
    isExpanded = !isExpanded;
    if(isExpanded){
        self.heightConstraint.constant = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    }else{
        self.heightConstraint.constant = CLOSED_HEIGHT;
    }
    ULFeedView *feedView = [self nearestAncestorOfClass:[UITableView class]];
    float faderTargetAlpha = isExpanded ? 0 : 1;
    self.opaque = NO;
    self.contentView.opaque = NO;
    self.fader.opaque = NO;


    [feedView beginUpdates];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.fader.alpha = faderTargetAlpha;
    }];
    [feedView endUpdates];
}
```

(I think variable and method names are self explanatory, `ULFeedView` is my custom table view class, and the code is in the custom cell class)

- I've tried animating the height constraint of my cell like I do with other views (`UIView animateWith... layoutIfNeeded` method): no luck.
- I've tried moving the alpha animation between `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` no luck.
- I've tried using different animation methods (animate with duration/delay etc), no luck.
- I've tried setting `opaque` to `NO` explicitly (following my own answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27680493/811405 on another question), no luck.
- I've tried with different Opaque, Clears Graphic Context, Clip Subviews settings, they don't seem to change anything at all.

Also, some interesting observations:

- The (only) subview of the view animates it's alpha correctly.
- When I'm setting the alpha from 1 to 0, the background color of the view that I'm animating jumps from 1 to 0 *at the beginning* of the animation.
- When I'm setting the alpha from 0 to 1, the background color of the view that I'm animating jumps from 0 to 1 *at the end* of the animation.
- I've tried setting a background color on the subview of the view that I'm animating too, and the above observations apply.

Why would this happen and how I do I animate both the background color of the view and the cell height at the same time? (I am targeting ≥ iOS 8.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after investigating a little bit, I've came up with a solution:

Seems that background colors don't play well with table view animations. Table view updates seem to mess up everything about background colors of any views inside the cell.

I've subclassed `UIView` and added a custom property called fade color (I could actually also use background color but I wanted to completely move away from it):

```
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface ULFaderView : UIView

@property IBInspectable UIColor *fadeColor;

@end
```

I've set the fade color on Interface Builder. And in code I've implemented custom drawing:

```
@implementation ULFaderView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClearRect(ctx, rect);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, self.fadeColor.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, rect);
}

@end
```

And it renders a background perfectly, duplicating the background color behavior. Yet as it's not the "background color property" which table view messes up, it doesn't conflict with any animations and acts as a "solid bitmap whatever content inside the view". Animating the alpha now works smooth as ever, while the table view also animates the height at the same time.